# Java regex to obtain value between parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Regular expression to obtain value from [[text]]. I have tried the regex

```
  "((?<=[[)*(?=]])*)+"  the value between [[ ]] is not obtained.
```

For example, from the string  [[text]], we should obtain text.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("((?<=\\[[)*(?=\\]])*)");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher("[[text]]");
String next ="";
while(matcher.find()) {
  next = matcher.group(0);
break;
}
System.out.println(next); //next should be text
```

Comment: please develop your answer... Explain better your problem, show code, etc...

Comment: What @MatiasCaamaño said -- suggestion: give an example. And can the value contain single `]` characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape brackets `[]` when using them as actual characters in a regular expression. And you also need to add something to actually capture what is between the brackets. You can use `.*` for that or use my approach, if you are sure the value cannot contain a `]`.

```
((?<=\[\[)([^\]]*)(?=\]\]))+
```

There is not even really a need to use lookbacks und lookaheads unless you explictly need to exempt those limiters from the match. This will work just as well:

```
 \[\[([\]]*\]\]
```

And obviously when you put these into a String, you need to add additional `\` to escape the `\` for the String...they are just more readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wanna get into `regex`, `String.replaceAll` can also help you.

```
String s2 = s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"(?<=\\[\\[)[^\\]]*"
```

this should work for you